# Use data from .env Laravel in Python

Tags: python, laravel

I have some data in my .env and I want to use them in a python file, but I am not sure how.

What I tried:

```
db_name = os.environ.pop('DB_DATABASE')  //on python file

DB_DATABASE=db_name //on .env
```

Comment: check this lib https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
ENV_FILE = find_dotenv()
if ENV_FILE:
load_dotenv(ENV_FILE)

db_name = env.get('DB_DATABASE')
```